# Crawler crawls for hours

Tags: 2013, search, crawl

I have single server farm SP2013 migrated from 2010 and the crawler is set up to perform a incremental crawl every 15minutes and a full crawl every friday evending.

Some times it hangs up for days and it never finishes:

[image]

What could the probelm be? I know that in order to improve the crawl performance the search service should have a dedicated/own server and set up a continuous crawl, but this is not possible for the moment. Obviously, by stopping and restart the SearchService it runs again ...for some weeks.

And what does `Successes`, `Warnings` and `Errors` exactly mean?

Edit:
I had to stop the crawl again, since it did not finish but the successes, warnings and errors do not increment.
After a while it restarted a full crawl by itself and I fear the scenario will repeat. For the weekend I'll try to reset the index and start the it again...hoping it works.

Update:
I resetted the index and started a full crawl during weekend, it did not finish.

[image]

Comment: There are various reasons your crawled sources might return warnings and/or errors. These include unassociated content databases, partially deleted IIS sites and too often ran crawling amongst others. Have a look at your Crawl Log page at the SSA and use the links to Warnings and Errors to see what lines have been returned as such.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably due to provisioning issues. Delete the Search Service Application from the Central Administration and re provision it.

> Central Administration -> Manage Service Applications

Comment: I'd definitely recommend **NOT** to straight away delete the SSA without first having a look at the related outputs such as logs.

Comment: True, but I answered about deleting it because I had faced a similar issue earlier, and this worked for me.

Comment: Well, when I restart the searchservice it runs fine again, but only for some weeks...I don't think that deleting and re provision the Search Service Application is the right way.

Comment: Try restarting the timer job and the IIS websites then.

Comment: @Emaborsa that suggests the crawling starts to overlap. There's probably some content which delays the crawling (remember that crawling is done at a cost of performance and vice versa). My shot at first would be to extend the interval between your incremental crawls.

Comment: In the incrementals usually (as we see in the picture) there are only few data to crawl and I don't think to extend the interval would solve my problem...Further, if I extend the interval, during this interval the new/edited data is not indexed yet, so excluded by the search.